# Child process reads data before data is being written to pipe using parent

Tags: c, pipe, fork, file-descriptor

I'm creating a child process using fork() and in the parent process I'm taking the input of 5 integers and saving it to an array. This data is then written to a pipe. The child process then will read the data from the pie and print it out to the screen.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#define INPUT 5

int main() {
    int     fd[2];
    pid_t   childprocess;

    if((childprocess = fork()) < 0) {
        perror("Cannot fork child");
    }

    if(childprocess > 0) {
        // Parent
        int userInput[INPUT];

        close(fd[0]);

        for(int i = 0; i < INPUT; i++) {
            printf("Enter number %d: ", i+1);
            scanf("%d", &userInput[i]);
        }

        write(fd[1], userInput, sizeof(userInput) + 1);

    } else {
        // Child
        close(fd[1]);

        int parentData[INPUT];

        read(fd[0], parentData, sizeof(parentData));

        for(int i = 0; i < INPUT; i++) {
            printf("%d => %d", i+1, parentData[i]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I run the program using ./a.out I observe the following behavior.

```
Enter number 1: 1 => -4731629522 => 327663 => 2005319684 => 15 => 1
```

Is there any mistake in the way pipe is implemented that causes this behavior?

Comment: You need to initialize the filedescriptors

Comment: @cmdLP This sorted the issue. Can you explain how the child process waits till the parent writes data? Is there any process synchronization mechanism involved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the filedescriptors are not initialized by the pipe-function. When the read-function is reached, `fd[0]` is probably an invalid file descriptor. 0 bytes are read, the integers, which are written to stdout are just what was in the uninitialized array `parentData`.
Just add:

```
pipe(fd);
```

**How does the synchronization work?**
When the `read` function is called with a valid filedescriptor, the kernel halts/blocks the process and waits until the requested amount of bytes (`sizeof parentData`) is written to the pipe by the other process. Then the kernel copies the bytes from the pipe. This is called blocking IO.

Note: when the writing process stops/closes the filedescriptor before the requested amount of bytes is reached, not all bytes are written to the buffer. The return value of `read` is the amount of read bytes.

There is also nonblocking IO. The process can do other things while waiting for the data. It is often implemented with a thread, which reads (with blocking IO) from the filedescriptor/socket(network IO) and sets a flag when finished.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This fixed the issue. Can you explain how the child process waits till the parent writes data? Is there any process synchronization mechanism involved?